# MySQL - Select the minimum value of a column after selecting the minimum value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following Table (tablea):

```
       x            y
---------------------------
      3            1 
      1            4
      1            3
```

As result i want x = 1 and y = 3 (Getting x as low as possible is the top priority, getting y as low as possible is a lower priority).
So I want an SQL Statement that is something like that:

```
Select Min(y), x 
FROM (SELECT MIN(x), y FROM tablea);
```

But this gives me following error code:

> Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

If i try that:

```
Select Min(y), x 
FROM (SELECT MIN(x), y FROM tablea) as a;
```

I get:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'

Comment: `Select Min(a.y), a.x 
FROM (SELECT MIN(x) AS x, y FROM tablea) as a;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid error `unknown column` you need to add allias to `MIN(x)`:

```
Select Min(a.y), a.x 
FROM (SELECT MIN(x) AS x, y FROM tablea) as a;
```

But to get results as you proposed I would rewrite your query as:

```
Select x, MIN(y) AS y
FROM tablea
WHERE x = (SELECT MIN(x) FROM tablea);
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33f76/4/0)**

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I know, I write it as example why he gets `unknown column` error. Then provided correct way to do it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I really happy that someone really review answers :)

Comment: @Jariel It will return MIN and MIN so you will get (1,1) not (1,3)

Comment: Oh i see. Didn't even notice it.

Comment: @Jariel The second is perfectly fine. I post first query as learning material why you get this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT x, y 
FROM tablea
order by x, y
limit 1
```

Comment: This is optimal with an index on `(x, y)`.